# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbf{f}(u) \cdot \nabla u \,dx=0$

Tags: analysis

> If $\mathbf{f}$ is a Lipschitz function such that $f_i(0)=0$ for each $i$, then show that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathbf{f}(u) \cdot \nabla u \,dx=0$ for every $u \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\mathbf{g}(u)= \int^{u}_{0} \mathbf{f}(s) \,ds$, then $\mathbf{g}'(u)=\mathbf{f}(u)$, now consider $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathbf{f}(u) \cdot \nabla u \,dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\mathbf{g}'(u) \cdot \nabla u\,dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{d}{dx} \mathbf{g}(u)=0 \quad \text{ as } u \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^d) $$